# z3 converting from bit vectors to integers

Tags: z3, smt, bitvector

There are several posts regarding the **conversion of bit vectors
to integers** (and vice versa) in z3. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273728/z3-covert-int-sort-into-bitvector),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821320/check-overflow-with-z3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000109/z3-converting-small-bitvectors-to-ints?rq=1).

The  [documentation](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/z3_api.h#L2877) says that **Z3_mk_bv2int** is uninterpreted:

> "...This function is essentially treated as uninterpreted.
>     So you cannot expect Z3 to precisely reflect the semantics of this 
>     function when solving constraints with this function..."

However, **I could not find a simple example** where it **does fail**
to reflect the expected semantics.
For instance, whenever I use queries like this:

```
(declare-const s String)
(declare-const someBitVec10 (_ BitVec 10))

(assert (= s "74g\x00!!#2#$$"))

(assert (str.in.re (str.at s (bv2int someBitVec10)) (re.range "1" "3")))

(check-sat)
(get-value (s someBitVec10))
```

I get a **correct** answer (index should 7, and it is)

```
sat
((s "74g\x00!!#2#$$")
 (someBitVec10 #b0000000111))
```

Could anyone please provide a simple example where z3's
**bv2int** and/or **int2bv** fail?? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is now resolved, as it turns out that both int2bv and bv2int are indeed **interpreted**. The documentation hasn't been updated, and this might have caused the confusion (at least in my case it did). All the details are in [this GitHub/z3/issues post](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1481#issuecomment-365030093).